# Detect a 180 rotation and delete the rotated element from array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to detect if the second picture b) with the below matrix of point is actually the first one a) after rotation and picture c) is not. First I like to remove duplicate point between two any matrix and detect if they are same after rotation. And if they are same after rotation, I would like to remove the second one.

```
def reverse(set1, set2):
    a_prime =[x for x in set1 if not x in set2]
    b_prime =[x for x in set1 if not x in set2]
    reverse = None  # will store a tuple of delta_x, delta_y
   for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(a_prime, b_prime):
        cur_reverse = x2 + x1, y1 + y2
        if not shift:  
            reverse = cur_reverse 
        elif shift != cur_reverse:
            return False 
    return True


a = [[(1, 1), (2, 1)], [(3, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], [(3, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)], [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3)]]
length = len(a)
for i in range(0, length):
    for j in range(1, length):
        if (i<j):
            if (is_shift(a[i], a[j])==True):
                a.remove(a[j])
            else:
                print(a[i])
                print(a[j])
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
            length -= 1
```

I [image]

Comment: one way to do it, is to put your data into a `numpy` array then use `rot90` with k=2 or k=-2 and then compare your arrays with `array_equal`

Comment: the rot90 function can rotate  in 2 dimension. Can we rotate in 3 dimension?

Comment: [yes we can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45872256/7540911)

Comment: can you show me how? I always got error 'raise ValueError("len(axes) must be 2.'

Comment: if (math.isclose(numpy.rot90(a[i], k=2, axes=(0, 1, 0)), a[j], rel_tol=1e-3)==True): a.remove(a[j])